# PineScript to draw box only on current candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

I want to draw a box with the following details:

```
left = current candle - 5
right = current candle
top = high for the selected 5 candles
bottom = low for the selected 5 candles
```

I wrote the following code:

```
highestClose = ta.highest(close, 5)
lowestClose = ta.lowest(close, 5)
box.new(bar_index-5, highestClose, bar_index, lowestClose, border_color=color.green, border_width=1,bgcolor=na)
```

But the code makes boxes for every candle

```
Image for reference - https://i.imgur.com/F27c5ky.png
```

I just want the box on the last 5 candles.
Also, is there any way to fill the box with some transparency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the box created to a variable, which will save it as a series, and on each bar delete the previous box created:

```
highestClose = ta.highest(close, 5)
lowestClose = ta.lowest(close, 5)
myBox = box.new(bar_index-5, highestClose, bar_index, lowestClose, border_color=color.green, border_width=1,bgcolor=na)
box.delete(myBox[1])
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thankss!!, can we add transparency to the fill color in the box?

Comment: Sure. in the `bgcolor` parameter of the `box.new()` function you can set the fill color. You can use the `color.new()` function to apply a color with transparency. For example: `bgcolor=color.new(color.green, 80)`